# Jena ARQ returns non-empty result for AVG() if there is no matching triple pattern

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I have a query that uses AVG() operator:

```
SELECT (AVG(?z) AS ?avg) { ?x <http://ex.com/value> ?z }
```

Let's imagine the triple store doesn't have triples matching the given triple pattern, then we expect *(at least I do)* that the query should return empty result. And Virtuoso actually returns empty result, you can use DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint to check ([execute](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%28AVG%28%3Fz%29%20AS%20%3Favg%29%20%7B%20%3Fx%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fex.com%2Fvalue%3E%20%3Fz%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)).

But Fuseki and Jena ARQ return non-empty result: `0`. You can check it on sparql.org ([execute](http://sparql.org/books/sparql?query=SELECT%20%28AVG%28%3Fz%29%20AS%20%3Favg%29%20%7B%20%3Fx%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fex.com%2Fvalue%3E%20%3Fz%20%7D&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl&force-accept=text%2Fplain)).

Is it possible to configure Jena ARQ to return an empty result for the given query? If so, then how?

Comment: I don't know whether you can change Jena's behavior, but if you do, it will be non conforming.  The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggAvg) that AVG() is supposed to return 0 if the set is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *we expect (at least I do) that the query should return empty result.
>   And Virtuoso actually returns empty result, you can use DBpedia's
>   SPARQL endpoint to check.*
>
> *But Fuseki and Jena ARQ return non-empty result: 0. You can check it
>   on sparql.org.*

I don't know whether you *can* change the behavior of **avg**, but you probably *shouldn't*, because Jena is doing the right thing here, and Virtuoso (the endpoint for DBpedia) is doing it wrong.  The SPARQL 1.1 standard specifically defines **avg** to return when the group is empty:

> #### [18.5.1.4 Avg](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggAvg)
>
> The Avg set function calculates the average value for an expression
>   over a group. It is defined in terms of Sum and Count.
>
> Definition: Avg numeric Avg(multiset M)
>
> Avg(M) = "0"^^xsd:integer, ***where Count(M) = 0***
>
> Avg(M) = Sum(M) / Count(M), where Count(M) > 0

That said, you can use **if** to check whether the count is zero, and return an undefined value in that case, and the average otherwise.  This should work with any endpoint, too, not just ARQ. I used values to introduce a variable with an undefined value here, but you could just as easily use an expression that will produce an error, e.g., **1/0**.  (Of course, the danger there is that implementations can extend the behavior of operators, so it's actually pretty hard to guarantee that any particular expression will be an error.)

```sql
select (if(count(?x) = 0,?undef,avg(?x)) as ?average) where {
      values ?x { 2 3 4 }
      values ?undef { undef }
}
group by ?undef
```

```
-----------
| average |
===========
| 3.0     |
-----------
```

And in the case where there are no values for ?x:

```sql
select (if(count(?x) = 0,?undef,avg(?x)) as ?average) where {
  values ?x {}
  values ?undef { undef }
}
group by ?undef
```

```
-----------
| average |
===========
|         |
-----------
```

Comment: Thanks @joshua-taylor for the answer! I have a specific use case, so I've created a custom implementation of AVG() which is quite easy to do in Jena.